# compare two columns using datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

My goal is to highlight a row if two columns contain the same string within a row using datatables
I am not sure how would I compare two columns. I want to do something like this.
This is part of my code

```
  "columnDefs":[
  {
      "targets":[3,4], 
      "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) { 
       if value of 3 = 4 {
         //highlight the row
       }
      }
   } ],
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Use [`rowCallback`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) option to define a callback function that will be called when row would be drawn.

```js
$('#example').dataTable({
  "rowCallback": function(row, data, index){
    if (data[3] === data[4]) {
       $(row).addClass('selected');
    }
  }
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1fa2ce3p/) for code and demonstration.